# How can I discard the largest and smallest numbers when I calculate the arithmetic mean?

Tags: java, math

My question is about discarding the largest and smallest number when my program calculates an arithmetic mean.

This is my code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k;
    int r;
    int thelargest;
    int thesmallest;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the list of number : ");
    String input2 = input.nextLine();

    String[] numbers = input2.split(" ");

    int[] result = new int[numbers.length];
    for (r = 0; r < numbers.length; r++) {
        result[r] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[r]);

    }

    for (k = 0; k < result.length; k++) {
        System.out.print("");
        System.out.println(result[k]);
    }

    System.out.println(" LargestNumber :  " + TheLargestNumber(result));
    System.out.println(" SmallestNumber :  " + TheSmallestNumber(result));
    thelargest = TheLargestNumber(result);
    thesmallest = TheSmallestNumber(result);
    System.out.println("The Arithmetic Mean : " + AirthmeticMean(result));

}

public static int TheSmallestNumber(int[] series) {
    int thesmallest = series[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < series.length; i++) {
        if (series[i] < thesmallest) {

            thesmallest = series[i];
        }
    }
    return thesmallest;
}

public static int TheLargestNumber(int[] series) {
    int thelargest = series[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < series.length; i++) {
        if (series[i] > thelargest) {

            thelargest = series[i];
        }
    }
    return thelargest;
}

public static float AirthmeticMean(int[] result) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        sum += result[i];
    }
    return (float) sum / result.length;
}
```

I tried to find the way and I wrote this sample but I don't know how to embed this code sample:

```
         for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (series[i] != thesmallest && series[i] != thelargest) {
            total = total + seriess[i];
        }
    }
```

Will this code sample be helpful to me?

Comment: When you iterate through the loop adding numbers, check for the largest and smallest number. Then after the loop is complete, subtract those numbers out of your sum. Easy as PI.

Comment: can you open it ?because I don't understand what to do .Showing on a code sample will be good for me .@HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: This doesn't work if the largest or smallest number occurs multiple times.

Comment: TheSmallestNumber better to have function names start with lower case like theSmallestNumber

Comment: http://jtf.acm.org/tutorial/Introduction.html this is ACM lib ?

Answer (score 0):

The code sample you've got:

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (series[i] != thesmallest && series[i] != thelargest) {
        total = total + seriess[i];
    }
}
```

is almost OK. Almost, because you retrieve the length of the array named `result` in the for-loop and access elements of array `series`.

You can use this code in the following way. Extend `AirthmeticMean` with two parameters `theSmallest` and `theLargest` and keep track of the number of summed elements:

```
public static float AirthmeticMean(int[] result, int theSmallest, int theLargest) {
    int sum = 0;
    int numElements = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i] != theSmallest && result[i] != theLargest) {
            sum += result[i];
            numElements++;
        }
    }
    return (float) sum / numElements;
}
```

EDIT: added `numElements`.

Comment: The last proposal doesn't work if the largest or smallest number occurs multiple times. (Poster edit: it had a solution where it subtracted the smallest and largest number out of the sum once.)

Comment: Thank you my friend .It works.Can I ask you one more last thing ?
Can I run this programme with using ACM libary(ConsoleProgram)?Do you have any information about this ?

Comment: @BarryNL I removed this suggestion. It depends on whether you discard the smallest and largest numbers at all or only once. I'd say it's a matter of definition :)

Comment: @mertha sorry, I can't help you with ACM libraries.

Comment: array list -> remove all occurrences of smallest and largest

Comment: @tgkprog what does mean "array list -> remove all occurrences of smallest and largest"? Do you have any idea about writing this program  with ACM libary(consoleprogram)?

Comment: @harpun you are not adding the smallest and largest but your are dividing using the total length? so if set was 2,3,5 the answer would be 3/3 = 1? it should be 3/1 = 3

Comment: @mertha no i do not know ACM do you have a link to it?

Comment: @tgkprog: you're right. I corrected the code. The ACM issue was discussed in another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387867/how-to-write-my-java-programme-with-acm-libraryconsoleprogram

Answer (score 0):

Just before your

```
System.out.println("The Arithmetic Mean : " + AirthmeticMean(result));
```

write

```
thenewmean = (AirthmeticMean(result)*result.length - thesmallest - thelargest)/(result.length-2)
```

and then print `thenewmean`

```
System.out.println("The Arithmetic Mean : " + thenewmean);
```

You don't need to write your

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (series[i] != thesmallest && series[i] != thelargest) {
        total = total + seriess[i];
    }
}
```

code anywhere. Even then if you wish to use your own code,
then use it in your `AirthmeticMean()` function

Comment: Your answer doesn't work if the largest or smallest number occurs multiple times.

Comment: yeah true...i didn't think about that

Answer (score 0):

Need to keep track of count as well as sum if removing highest and smallest

```
public static float AirthmeticMean(int[] result, int theSmallest, int theLargest) {
    int sum = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i] != theSmallest && result[i] != theLargest) {
                sum += result[i];
                cnt++;
            }
    }
    return (float) sum / cnt;
}
```